# I CAN log into Jira through proxy. I CAN get to login page from local host. Authentication fails ONLY from local host

Tags: authentication, oauth, jira

I'm having the strangest problem with Jira.

We were in the process of setting up links between Jira and Confluence and everything seemed to be working.  After a restart of the machine we had some startup issues due to disabled plugs.  We resolved this by deleting the rows indicating inactive plugins in the MySql database.

Everything seemed to be working.  Could log into Jira.  Could log into Confluence.  Could connect from each to the other using application linker widget in the upper left corner of the applications.

While trying to embed some Jira into a Confluence page a user got an error and we checked the Application links.

Application link from Jira to Confluence looks good.

Application link from  Confluence to Jira looks like this.

[image]

If I log onto the host machine and try to log into Jira as http://localhost:8080 i get this very strange behavior:

http://localhost:8080 brings up my Jira log on page.

If I try to log on as userX I get a try again screen.

If I try to log on as userY I get a try again screen WITH A CAPCHA.

BOTH logons DO WORK if I try to logon from https://jira.myorg.com!!!

Really confused why I can access the application but authentication fails.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still seeing this strange behavior but I've solved the problem by changing the application url to the outward facing one (https://jira.myorg.com).  At one point this didn't work (that's why we used http://localhost:8080 in the first place, jira and confluence are on the same server).  It seems to not need this at this point.

We did delete and recreate the links from scratch also.  This is mention as a suggestion in the documentation if you are having problems with the links.